# Wie heißen "Aufschriebe" richtig?

Tags: single-word-request

Studierende oder Schüler schreiben im Unterricht oder in der Vorlesung mit (Mitschrift), schreiben bei der Lektüre Wichtiges aus Texten heraus (Exzerpt) und ordnen und strukturieren ihr solcherart gesammeltes Wissen (Skript). Wie heißt die Gesamtheit all dieser selbst erstellten handschriftlichen Lernmaterialien? Bei uns heißt das "Aufschriebe", aber das Wort finde ich in keinem Wörterbuch. Wie heißt es richtig? Oder gibt's doch ein Wörterbuch, das den "Aufschrieb" verzeichnet?

[image]

*Bild: [Kunterbunter Beautyblog](http://kunterbunter-beautyblog.blogspot.com/2016/03/successfull-studying-meine-lerntipps.html)*

---

»Wollen wir zusammen auf die Klausur lernen?«
»Gerne. Ich bringe meine Bücher und meine Aufschriebe mit.«

---

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

---

Das Wort "Aufschrieb" ist möglicherweise eher Oberdeutsch. Viele der Bücher, die auf Google Books dieses Wort (als Substantiv) enthalten, haben einen Bezug zu Württemberg oder der Schweiz; und das Schweizerische Idiotikon verzeichnet es (als [Ûfschrib](https://digital.idiotikon.ch/idtkn/id9.htm#!page/91559/mode/1up), ganz unten in Spalte 1560).

Comment: Wo ist das genau, "bei uns"?

Comment: Also *bei uns* hieß das Mitschrift.

Comment: @Beta "Bei uns" ist hier: https://www.google.de/search?#tbm=bks&q="aufschriebe"

Comment: _Kladde_ bzw. _Kladden_, _Aufzeichnungen_, _Loseblattsammlung_, _Notizen_, _Block_, _Mappe_, _Schmierblätter_, _Gedächtnisstützen_

Comment: Haben wir rein dekorative Bilder, als Eyecatcher, die nichts zum Verständnis beitragen, schon diskutiert? Ich halte davon wenig und fürchte ein Wettrüsten.

Answer (score 10):

Man hat von der Tafel abgeschrieben oder während des Unterrichts/Vorlesung mitgeschrieben und das Erzeugnis beider kenne ich zusammenfassend als *[Mitschrift](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Mitschrift)*.
Das Wort findet sich auch [im Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Mitschrift).

*Aufschrieb* ist mir nicht geläufig. Als Gesamtheit würde ich alle meine Niederschriften am ehesten als *Aufzeichnungen* bezeichnen. Oder ich würde die Sachen konkret beim Namen nennen, also *Mitschriften* und *Zusammenfassungen*.

Comment: Danke für deine Antwort. Leider hast du nur einen der genannten Aspekte erfasst. Nachdem ich gesehen habe, wie meine Frage missverstanden wurde, habe ich die Frage überarbeitet. Gesucht sind nicht die Begriffe "Mitschrift", "Exzerpt" und "Skript".

Comment: Ich würde eher zu dem in der Antwort genannten _Niederschriften_ tendieren. _Exzerpt_ kenne ich so nicht, stattdessen  _Auszug_.

Answer (score 2):

Als Studenten nannten wir es "Mitschriften". Oder es wird vom Professor ein offizielles "Vorlesungsskript" herausgegeben. Für die Schüler kenne ich kein spezielles Wort. Vielleicht "Zusammenfassung".

Comment: Bei mir hat das in der Schule auch immer Mitschrift geheißen.

Comment: von der Tafel abschreiben, ja. Aber die Frage war ja bezüglich der Schulbücher.

Comment: @ladybug wenn man das speziell unterscheiden will (warum auch immer), ist vielleicht *Abschrift* das gesuchte Wort.

Comment: @Chieron Eine "Abschrift" wäre aber eine unveränderte Kopie.

Comment: Danke für deine Antwort, @ladybug. Leider hast du nur einen der genannten Aspekte erfasst. Nachdem ich gesehen habe, wie meine Frage missverstanden wurde, habe ich die Frage überarbeitet. Gesucht sind nicht die Begriffe "Mitschrift", "Exzerpt" und "Skript".

Answer (score 2):

Natürlich gibt es das Wort *Aufschrieb* - Das zeigen schon deine Beispiele.

Normalerweise würde das Substantiv als "Aufschrift" gebildet, aber dieses Wort hat eben schon eine andere Bedeutung.

Fragt man **Google ngrams**, so finden sich zwar viele Fundstellen mit der Verbform in der Vergangenheit (deswegen ist es nicht sinnvoll, das Diagramm hier zu zeigen), aber auch durchaus einige Erwähnungen einer Substantivierung in den Fundstellen.

Duden erwähnt zwar den *Aufschrieb* nicht direkt, aber scheint mit der Bildung des Substantivs leben zu können: Es gibt einen *Tafelanschrieb* (erstaunlich, im Übrigen, wie ich finde).

Wenn ein Wort im Duden (und vielleicht auch in anderen Wörterbüchern) nicht vorkommt, heisst das noch lange nicht, dass es dieses Wort nicht gibt. Durch die Möglichkeiten, mit denen man im Deutschen Wörter bilden kann (Zusammensetzungen, Substantivierungen,...) *kann* ein Wörterbuch niemals alle (vor allem die eher ungebräuchlichen) Worter erfassen.

Das Wort wird übrigens auch von Ralleyfahrern (eher den Beifahrern) als deutscher Begriff für das englische "roadbook" verwendet.

Comment: Danke, @tofro. Mein Eindruck, nach etwas Recherche, ist, dass "Aufschrieb" dialektal oder regional ist (Alemannisch). Meine Erwartung wäre, dass es in anderen Regionen oder im Hochdeutschen ein Wort mit entsprechender Bedeutung gibt, da es die Sache ja überall gibt. Die Frage fragt also, welches andere Wort *überregional* gebräuchlich ist und idealerweise auch zur Standardsprache gehört. Dass ein Wort nicht im Duden steht, zeigt ja doch wenigstens dass es nicht sehr verbreitet ist, aber Aufschriebe sind ja nun doch etwas, das Schüler und Studenten überall produzieren.

Comment: @what Der "*Aufschrieb* der Ralley-Fahrer wird sehr wohl überregional verwendet, und findet sich sogar in der Wikipedia. Warum soll dann der der Schüler und Studenten nur regional verbreitet sein?